# Counting the appearance of words in a vector and listing those in a list, C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, counter

I have a cpp vector containing separate words and I need to count how many times a word appears using a list. I try to iterate through the list but failing with the comparison of the two STL containers, whether the following word is already in my list or not. If not, I want to add that word to my list with an appearance of 1. I have a struct that counts the times a word appeared in the text. 
The following code returns a list of words and numbers, but not each in my vector and I can't see why.

```
struct counter{
    string word;
    int sum = 1;
    counter(){};
    counter(string word): word(word){};
};

list<counter> list_count(vector<string> &text){
    list<counter> word_count;
    list<counter>::iterator it = word_count.begin();
    for(string t:text){
        if(it != word_count.end()){
            it -> sum++;
        } else {
            word_count.push_back(counter(t));
        }
        ++it;
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are specifically required to use a `list`? Just asking to eliminate some low-hanging fruit from the possible answers. A `std::map` makes frequency counting dead simple.

Comment: In the code above `it != word_count.end()` will never be true.

Comment: Yes, I need to do that woth both list and map. I managed the map version, it was sure easier.

Comment: @blntms You should use `std::find_if` on your list.

Comment: @john good point

Comment: If your teacher is teaching you to use `std::list`. **RUN** ... fast! They don't know what they're teaching.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually searching the `std::list` at all.  On every loop iteration through the `std::vector`, you need to search the entire `std::list` from front to back, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct counter {
    string word;
    int sum = 1;
    counter(const string &word): word(word) {}
};

list<counter> list_count(const vector<string> &text) {
    list<counter> word_count;
    for(const string &t: text) {
        // perform an actual search here!
        list<counter>::iterator it = find_if(
            word_count.begin(), word_count.end(),
            [&](counter &c){ return (c.word == t); }
        );
        if (it != word_count.end()) {
            it->sum++;
        } else {
            word_count.emplace_back(t);
        }
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/KTZyy3)

That being said, a `std::list` is a poor solution for counting elements.  A better solution is to use a `std::(unordered_)map` instead (unless you need to preserve the order of the words found, which neither one will do), eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> list_count(const vector<string> &text) {
    map<string, int> word_count;
    for(const string &t: text) {
        word_count[t]++;
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mmZUiR) (using `std::map`)

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/BKhUpX) (using `std::unordered_map`)

Answer (score 0):

```
list<counter> list_count(const vector<string>& text) {
    list<counter> word_count;
    for (const string& t : text) {
        auto it = std::find_if(word_count.begin(), word_count.end(), 
            [&](const counter& c){ return c.word == t; });
        if (it != word_count.end()) {
            it -> sum++;
        } else {
            word_count.push_back(counter(t));
        }
    }
    return word_count;
}
```

Untested code.

Comment: thank you both @john. the problem is still occuring, i receive an error that 'find_if is not a member of std', which is odd

Comment: @blntms You need to `#include <algorithm>` for `std::find_if`.

Comment: @john Yes, forgot that and it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: @Remy Lebeau yes, i thought it was included already. Many thanks you too!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an inefficient approach. The standard class template list does not have random access to its elements. Each new element is appended to the end of the list. To find whether an element is already present in the list elements of it are traversed sequentially.

It would be much efficiently to use the standard container `std::map` . Moreover in this container words will be ordered.

For example you could declare

```
std::map<std::string, size_t> counters;
```

Nevertheless if you want to use the list then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct counter
{
    std::string word;
    size_t n = 0;
    counter() = default;
    counter( const std::string &word ): word( word ), n( 1 ){}
};

std::list<counter> list_count( const std::vector<std::string> &text )
{
    std::list<counter> word_count;

    for ( const auto &s : text )
    {
        auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( word_count ), std::end( word_count ),
                                [&s]( const auto &c ) { return c.word == s; } );

        if ( it == std::end( word_count ) )
        {
            word_count.push_back( s );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it->n;
        }
    }

    return word_count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "first", "second", "first" };

    auto word_count = list_count( v );

    for ( const auto &c : word_count )
    {
        std::cout << c.word << ": " << c.n << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
first: 2
second: 1
```

Pay attention to that the definition of the struct counter is redundant. You could use instead the standard class std::pair. Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> list_count( const std::vector<std::string> &text )
{
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> word_count;

    for ( const auto &s : text )
    {
        auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( word_count ), std::end( word_count ),
                                [&s]( const auto &p ) { return p.first == s; } );

        if ( it == std::end( word_count ) )
        {
            word_count.emplace_back( s, 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it->second;
        }
    }

    return word_count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "first", "second", "first" };

    auto word_count = list_count( v );

    for ( const auto &p : word_count )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to use `std::map` then the function will look very simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, size_t> list_count( const std::vector<std::string> &text )
{
    std::map<std::string, size_t> word_count;

    for ( const auto &s : text )
    {
        ++word_count[s];
    }

    return word_count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "first", "second", "first" };

    auto word_count = list_count( v );

    for ( const auto &p : word_count )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using of the list will be efficient only in the case when the vector of strings is sorted.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct counter
{
    std::string word;
    size_t n = 0;
    counter() = default;
    counter( const std::string &word ): word( word ), n( 1 ){}
};

std::list<counter> list_count( const std::vector<std::string> &text )
{
    std::list<counter> word_count;

    for ( const auto &s : text )
    {
        if ( word_count.empty() || word_count.back().word != s )
        {
            word_count.push_back( s );          
        }
        else
        {
            ++word_count.back().n;
        }
    }

    return word_count;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E" };

    auto word_count = list_count( v );

    for ( const auto &c : word_count )
    {
        std::cout << c.word << ": " << c.n << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3
D: 2
E: 1
```